# How can we show that the $k$th order statistic is measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, order-theory, machine-learning, order-statistics

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(E,\le)$ be a partially ordered set and $\mathcal E$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$
- $n\in\mathbb N$
- $X_1,\ldots,X_n:\Omega\to E$ be $(\mathcal A,\mathcal E)$-measurable, $$X_{1:n}:=\min\left\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\right\}$$ and $$X_{i:n}:=\min\left\{X_j:X_j>X_{i-1:n}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }j\in\left\{2,\ldots,n\right\}.\tag1$$

> **Question 1**: The definition $(1)$ is broken, unless at least almost surely $X_i\ne X_j$ for all $i\ne j$. Can we fix the definition such that $X_{1:n}\le\cdots\le X_{n:n}$ even when $X_1=\cdots=X_n$, where a tie is broken by declaring that $X_i$ is smaller than $X_j$ whenever $X_i=X_j$ and $i<j$?
>
> **Question 2**: Given the fixed definition, are we able to show that each $X_{i:n}$ is $(\Omega,\mathcal E)$-measurable? This is clear to me when $X_i\ne X_j$ for all $i\ne j$ and $(E,\mathcal E)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ in which case the minimum is a continuous function. So, maybe we need to impose further conditions on $\mathcal E$ and its relation to $\le$.

Comment: Even if the $X_i$ are not all distinct, there's nothing wrong with that definition. Remember that $X_{1:n}$ is only the *value*  of the minimum, not the index $i$ of the minimum $X_i$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need extra assumption on the sigma algebra $\mathcal E$? Surely you need some sort of relation to hold between $\mathcal E$ and the partial order $\leq$.

Comment: @JackM Yes, it's somehow part of the question how $\mathcal E$ and $\le$ need to be related. I made that clear in an edit.

Comment: @JackM If they are all equal, then the set over which the $(1)$ minimum is taken is empty, isn't it?